# Using WeakEventManager with a static event

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Is it possible to create a weak event listener on a static event using WeakEventManager?

I would like to create a weak event listener on the static CompositionTarget.Rendering event to avoid memory leaks when I don't know the lifetime of the WPF/Silverlight source element.

I implemented the rendering event manager by the [weak event pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx):

```
public class RenderingEventManager : WeakEventManager
{
    public static void AddListener(IWeakEventListener listener)
    {
        CurrentManager.ProtectedAddListener(null, listener);
    }

    public static void RemoveListener(IWeakEventListener listener)
    {
        CurrentManager.ProtectedRemoveListener(null, listener);
    }

    private static RenderingEventManager CurrentManager
    {
        get
        {
            var managerType = typeof(RenderingEventManager);
            var manager = (RenderingEventManager)GetCurrentManager(managerType);
            if (manager == null)
            {
                manager = new RenderingEventManager();
                SetCurrentManager(managerType, manager);
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }

    protected sealed override void StartListening(object source)
    {
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += this.OnCompositionTargetRendering;
    }

    protected sealed override void StopListening(object source)
    {
        CompositionTarget.Rendering -= this.OnCompositionTargetRendering;
    }

    void OnCompositionTargetRendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DeliverEvent(sender, e);
    }
}
```

and tested the manager in a simple window:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, IWeakEventListener
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RenderingEventManager.AddListener(this);
    }

    bool IWeakEventListener.ReceiveWeakEvent(Type managerType, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The ReceiveWeakEvent method is not being called. OnCompositionTargetRendering is called, but it seems like DeliverEvent does not work as I expected.
Adding listeners to instance events like Button.Click works fine...
The test project is on .NET 4.0 Client Profile.

[A post on Microsoft Connect from 2009](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/393127/the-weakeventmanager-doesnt-work-with-static-events) states that static events are not supported,
but I checked the WeakEventManager source code, and it looks ok:

```
    protected void ProtectedAddListener(object source, IWeakEventListener listener) 
    { 
        Debug.Assert(listener != null, "Listener cannot be null");

        object sourceKey = (source != null) ? source : StaticSource;
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out myself: change the **sender** argument of the DeliverEvent method to null:

```
void OnCompositionTargetRendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DeliverEvent(null, e);
}
```