# WeakEventManager and static event

Tags: c#, generics, weakeventmanager

I am trying to get used to `WeakEventManager` and I stumble with following:

---

[image]

---

The *only* difference between `A` and `B` is `static`, please ignore copy/paste error with `nameof`  ;)

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5858670/1997232) regarding generics and static types, but I wonder what [`WeakEventManager`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/WeakEventManagerT.cs,a795c952f2e86713,references) is doing with `A` then? Somehow it can work with `null` as source of static event.

I am seeking for a simple answer why `static` event is ok, but `static class` as `TEventSource` suddenly is not.

---

Code:

```
public class A
{
    public static event EventHandler Event;
}

public static class B
{
    public static event EventHandler Event;
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WeakEventManager<A, EventArgs>.AddHandler(null, nameof(A.Event), (s, e) => { });
        WeakEventManager<B, EventArgs>.AddHandler(null, nameof(B.Event), (s, e) => { });
    }
}
```

Error:

> Error CS0718
> 'B': static types cannot be used as type arguments

Comment: Could you please write your code as text in the question?

Comment: Normally I do, but why do you need the code in this case? To reproduce the problem? Really? Or in case picture will rot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - static types cannot be used as type arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858591/c-sharp-static-types-cannot-be-used-as-type-arguments)

Comment: @Hendry, I have that question answer mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Sinatr - The edit is an improvement, the code needs to be discoverable by Google. But you left out the error message.

Comment: You are correct, but I think the accepted answer in the linked question perfectly explains it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I see the point now, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WeakEventManager` can deal with static events, when `source` is [null](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/WeakEventManager.cs,274):

```
object sourceKey = (source != null) ? source : StaticSource;
```

where `StaticSource` is a special "event source" for static events.
This is implementation details of `WeakEventManager`, and that's why it's OK.

About static types as generic parameter - this is language limitation. It isn't related specifically to `WeakEventManager`.

Comment: I thought `WeakEventManager` will use `null` as key and perform differently for `static` and normal events. It seems instead it perform similarly, using `StaticSource` instance for static events. Thanks. Regarding language limitation, this is simply pity, required to remove `static` from pure static classes (no instance members) only to be able to subscribe to its events via `WeakEventManager`. From other point writing non-generic event manager for each static type is even more troublesome.

Comment: I'd bet, that primary goal for generic `WeakEventManager` is to help to handle instance events. In fact, static events are rather rare things. If your code is full of static events and/or static classes, it is better to refactor your code instead of inventing workarounds

Comment: There's a good solution on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876112/using-weakeventmanager-with-a-static-event